# Datediff in WHERE clause not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following script. I need to get all the visits where customers came back within 30 days. Everything works fine in the script but the datediff in the where clause. Could someone please help me fix the logic?

```
select OverallNumber,VisitID,coalesce(CheckInDateTime,ServiceDateTime) as ArrivalDateTime, DepartDateTime
from Visits 
where OverallNumber='100'
and DepartDateTime is not null
and coalesce(CheckInDateTime,ServiceDateTime) is not null
--and DATEDIFF(day,MIN(coalesce(CheckInDateTime,ServiceDateTime)), Max(DepartDateTime))<30
order by ArrivalDateTime;
```

Current data:

```
OverallNumber   VisitID ArrivalDateTime DepartDateTime
100              1      6/13/2015       6/15/2015
100              2      11/5/2015       11/7/2015
100              3      11/20/2015      11/25/2015

Desired:
OverallNumber   VisitID ArrivalDateTime DepartDateTime
    100              2      11/5/2015       11/7/2015
    100              3      11/20/2015      11/25/2015
```

In this example customer came back twice from 11/5/2015 to 11/25/2015. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You can't put a MIN() in the WHERE clause.   Use a CTE, sub-select or derived table.

Comment: Hi Tab! I get that but I will later be transferring this script to another application so I am trying to avoid using CTE or anything complex. I was wondering if I should do a dateadd or sub-query. Just not being able to figure out.

Comment: if you're transferring the script to another application that's also using sql 2012 you can use the Lag function to get your results https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

Comment: I will look at lag function. I also noticed that using datediff min will pick 6/13/2015 so there will be an issue getting rid of the visits not falling in the 30 day period. This is just getting headache now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT OverallNumber,
        VisitID,
        ArrivalDateTime,
        DepartDateTime
FROM (
    SELECT
        OverallNumber,
        VisitID,
        ArrivalDateTime,
        DepartDateTime,
        LAG(DepartDateTime, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY OverallNumber ORDER BY ArrivalDateTime) PreviousDateDiff,
        LEAD(ArrivalDateTime, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY OverallNumber ORDER BY ArrivalDateTime) NextDateDiff
    FROM (
        SELECT  
            *, 
            COALESCE(CheckInDateTime,ServiceDateTime) ArrivalDateTime 
        FROM    
            Visits
        WHERE
            OverallNumber = '100'
            AND DepartDateTime IS NOT NULL) t         
    ) v
WHERE 
    ArrivalDateTime < DATEADD(day, 30, PreviousDateDiff)
    OR DATEADD(day, -30, NextDateDiff) < DepartDateTime
ORDER BY
    ArrivalDateTime;
```

The Lag will give you the previous `DepartDateTime` and the Lead function will give you the next `ArrivalDateTime`

Comment: This still gave me all the previous visits before the 30 days.

Comment: if i take your `Current Data` and run the query against it.. i only get your `Desired` result.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/66bea/1

Comment: Yeah, I recreated a fiddle with checkindate and servicedata. Your query gave me the desired output. Thanks a lot. Let me play around a bit then will mark the answer. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f15f/1